# Different implementations for abstract class in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class, subclass, superclass

I'm building a maze game where the player has to navigate a maze with enemies chasing after him.

I'm wondering what would be the best way to implement an Enemy class with "Zombie" and "Vampire" subclasses. At the moment both classes are practically identical, except for their color. The movement strategies are the same however this could potentially change in the future. Also I want to allow extensibility in the sense that if a client wants to add more enemies with different movement strategies than they would be able to do so without changing the existing code base.

I was looking at different ways to do it:

1. Just use an Enemy class that takes in a string in it's constructor and decides what color to make that "Enemy" depending whether "Zombie" or "Vampire" was passed in. However this doesn't allow for different movement strategies and there will be a build up of conditional branches if many other enemies are added.
2. Abstract Enemy class with abstract method `move()` and `getColor()`, this allows each class to define its own movement strategy and hold a reference to it's color. However isn't this a bit overkill if enemies will likely only differ in color. Enemy movement will all be the same in my implementation but showcasing potential for extensibility is always a plus.

Comment: I would definitely go for the second option! Use an abstract Enemy class with common methods implemented and uncommon methods declared abstract. Zombies and Vampires extend Enemy, so they have to implement its abstract methods.

Comment: The only problem with this is that right now, my Zombie and Vampire move() implementations will be the same. Is this bad design practice?

Comment: Yes, it is better if you write the same piece of code only once. What will happen if you forget to update only the one method? Implement this on the Enemy class and if you later on need to change it in another class, you can override it.

Comment: If that's the case then you can just define the 'defaukt' move() method in the abstract class, and not ovverride it in the Zombie and Vampire subclasses.

Comment: @Dg123 If you want to get slightly more complicated, you could always build a movement "strategy" and then construct your enemy with that.  That allows you to change the movement dynamically (say, if the enemy gets hungry or sunlight is coming).

Comment: This is not a suitable question for Stackoverflow. Ask this kind of questions on [Programmers (Stackexchange)](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If I follow this route than my subclasses will be empty, as they use the superclasses move method()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would go with option 1)

**Reason**

As i understand OPs problem each Enemy has the same methods and attributes. Just their movement strategy differs. So i would generate a abstract class `MovementStrategy` (as the name already implies you should consider the strategy pattern). Just add a member with type `MovementStrategy` to the `Enemy`-class and delegate the `nextMove`method to this object. So can each Zombie have other strategies too (easy/hard mode).

You can also consider a basic behaviour in this class. A hierarchy on the Enemy class isnt a good option (IMO) when this is the only thing they differ.

**BUT**

This only applies if the requirements dont change drastically!

**Edit**

as hinted in the comment : in this case, you cannot construct the object with just a String.

**Edit 2**

Nothing stops you with this variant to subclass `Enemy` too, but not because they strategies differ.
What i dont like about the way e.g. `aleksamarkoni` "would" implement option 2 is, that he define constants for variables in the supertype. So you literally remove the point on having variables in the first place with constants (classes are no objects!).
What if another Zombie have a different shade of green? Would you generate a third class of Zombies with another shade (class LighterGreenZombie)? So basically what is the difference between Zombies and Vampires? Nothing except color and name and movement strategy! With these requirements decoupling the movement-strategy makes it pointless to subclass enemy altogether and is much more clean!

Comment: And how about passing a color and a movement strategy as arguments to the constructor instead of a string?

Comment: Enemy is already implementing State strategy. Hard/Medium/Easy have different movements for Enemy class as a whole, does not differentiate between subclasses

Comment: @Dd123 maybe i dont understand your problem here correctly. But why dont you do it to decouple the behaviour altogther? Maybe a movement strategy for Subclass1 on Easy is the strategy for Subclass2 on hard. This way you wont repeat yourself anytime

Answer (score 1):

I would have created an interface for every part of the game such as movement, attack or npc(ness). Create an undead enemy class which implements all the interfaces and then extend it with vampire and zombie class only to override the color property retrieval method. I wouldn't have used an abstract class at all.

Comment: While agreeing using Interface is good, how exactly differs your undead class from OPs enemy class with option 2? So basically you would subclass undead class too for different movementstrategies

Comment: A movement strategy is dependant on the class. If the vampire moves like an undead than it shall simple inherit from the undead. However if not, it will override and thereby have a movement strategy of its own. Punchline here is not using an abstract class because as the project grows in the example above, I can tell that eventually all methods would have to be abstract. In time there would just be too little in common for the enemies overall (they would move differently, act differently, fight differently and so on ) making the usage of abstract obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Second option is better than the first one, especially if you are going to include the new type of enemies. If you have the same movement for this two types of enemies, you can put your move code in abstract enemy class, so zombie and vampire can share it. Here is the way I would do it.

```
public abstract class Enemy {
    // every enemy has the color, so you can put it here
    protected String color;
    public void move() {
        // your basic move strategy here, this will include both the zombie and the vampire
    }
}

public class Zombie extends Enemy{

    // default constructor lets say zombies are black
    public Zombie() {
        color = "black";
    }

    // or you can have some color added throught constructor
    public Zombie(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    // you dont have to override move function, because its the same as Enemy one
}

public class Vampire extends Enemy {

    // default constructor lets say vampires are red
    public Zombie() {
        color = "red";
    }

    // or you can have some color added throught constructor
    public Zombie(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    // you dont have to override move function, because its the same as Enemy one
}

public class NewEnemy extends Enemy {

    // default constructor lets say new enemy is green
    public Zombie() {
        color = "green";
    }

    // or you can have some color added throught constructor
    public Zombie(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    // lets say new enemy has diffrent move strategy
    @Override 
    public void move() {
        // new move strategy, only for the new enemy
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second option is by far the better choice, seeing that in the future if you want to make more enemies that share similar features you can just extend the abstract class again.

Also if you want to add unique elements to each enemy you can change the respective sub classes rather then messing with the main Enemy class.

Finally, if you want to add a new abstract trait/method to each enemy doing so in the main abstract Enemy class will force you to implement it in each sub class ensuring that you make consistent changes across the board.